# Shortest subarray containing all elements without using arrays?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, functional-programming, ml

Problem: Find the length of the shortest subarray that contains all elements
Example : 1 2 2 3 2 2 1 3
Answer :  3

I have read that the best approach to this problem is by using the sliding window approach. But this approach requires using arrays. Is there any other efficient approach that does not require to use arrays by storing the number of appearances of each element? ( I would like to use this approach without arrays by writing it in ML )

Comment: is ML Mark Logic?

Comment: ML the programming language : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_(programming_language)

Comment: I have an idea, but it requires some restriction on the input. Can 0 be a valid item? Can a negative integer be a valid item? Could the input be non-integer?

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich No the numbers on the input are natural (1,2,3,...)

Comment: If the array has a 5 does that mean it must have also 1,2,3,4? Or could the array be like [1,2,2,5,2,1]?

Comment: @beaker for some reason it wasn't an option

Comment: @trincot it should contain all elements so 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the reason you want to avoid an array is that you want to write *idiomatic* ML code, and so would prefer to use a purely functional data structure rather than a mutable array?

If so, then you can use a [purely functional red-black tree](https://www.google.com/search?q=purely+functional+red-black+tree) for the "sliding-window" approach in almost exactly the same way as you would use an array; the only differences are:

- Instead of *O*(1) lookups, you have *O*(log *m*) lookups, where *m* is the number of distinct elements.
- Instead of *O*(1) mutations, you have *O*(log *m*) transformations, where a transformation returns a modified copy of the map (sharing most of its nodes).

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for . I am quite new to ML so could you provide some code or an algorithm to make it easier?

Comment: @maverick98: Could you be more specific about the code you're looking for? (A full implementation of red-black trees, plus a full implementation of a function that uses such a tree to solve the problem in your question, is probably too much for a single Stack Overflow answer. You can get an implementation of purely functional red-black trees via Google, and while I'm happy to help you write a function that uses one, you should really give it a try yourself first.)

Comment: Actually I dont know how would I call the red-black tree , or how would I implenent it in a way that it would replace the array that is used in the “sliding window”

Comment: @maverick98: I'm sorry, that still seems too broad. Functional programming is a very different paradigm, and it's to be expected that you'll struggle a bit with it. (You may want to start with simpler problems.) But asking someone to write the code for you is not really going to help you learn. :-/

Comment: I am not asking for code necessarily , I just don't understand how would I use the red-black tree to replace the array. When , How would I call it?

Comment: @maverick98: Use the elements of the list (in your case 1, 2, and 3) as the keys of the red-black tree, and the element-counts as the values.

Answer (score -3):

I don't understand your problem with arrays. You don't specify which ML-family language you are using but Ocaml (my favorite one) certainly has arrays. If you really don't like arrays for some religious reason, you can always use a Map with integer keys which does the same thing as an array but a lot slower.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an answer.